# Get HTML element by position

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I am using `TWebBrowser` in Delphi.
I need help to get an HTML element by its position.

The element I need is in a frame. Using `elementFromPoint()`:

```
Document.elementFromPoint(X, Y)
```

I am getting the frame itself, but not what is inside of it.

I tried to get it using this:

```
WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.Frames
```

But this gives me an access error when transferring frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Document.elementFromPoint()` is the correct approach.  What you are not taking into account is that the HTML is parsed in a hierarchical DOM tree and `elementFromPoint()` is not recursive.

You are asking the browser's top-level Document to find *an immediate child* element at a given X,Y coordinate within the Document.  In this case, that is a frame element.

A frame is an embedded window that holds another Document.  You need to access the frame's Document and ask it to find a child element at the target X,Y coordinate within the frame. And so on, and so on, until you finally reach the bottom-most child.

Note that `elementFromPoint()` takes **client** coordinates that are relative to the top-left corner of the Document you are calling `elementFromPoint()` on.  So, when you want to search a child frame's Document, you need to first subtract the frame's own top-left X,Y coordinate (within its parent Document) from the target X,Y coordinate before calling `elementFromPoint()` on the frame's Document.

Comment: How can I get access to the frame? `WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.Frames`
this does not work. Access error.

Comment: You already have access to the frame from `elementFromPoint()`, it returns the actual frame element. You don't need to use `Document.Frames` at all.

Comment: how do I get the element from the frame? `frame:=browser.elementFromPoint(x,y); ... element:=frame.elementFromPoint(frame_x, frame_y);`

Comment: @Alexey if you read MSDN's documentation on the browser interfaces, you would know how to do that. Depending on which version of IE `TWebBrowser` is wrapping, a frame element has a `ContentDocument` or `ContentWindow.Document` property, eg: `element := frame.ContentDocument.elementFromPoint(...);` or `element := frame.ContentWindow.Document.elementFromPoint(...);`

Comment: thank you. I'm working with DSEF3. It is implemented through JS, it suits me.